# How get path to file from List<File> and put to the another list

Tags: java, list

EDIT
It's my list with values from List listQuestion now i need to add pathFile like extra value to this list.

My code look like this

```
private static List<String> listQuestionE(Scanner sc, List<File> listQuestion){
       //List with value from List<File> listQuestion ( its some value from .log files it doesn't matter
       List<String> question = new ArrayList<String>();
       //I think that I need to do something with File input1 but i try several things and it doesnt work for me.
       for(File input1 : listaQuestion){
           try {
              sc = new Scanner(input1);
           } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
           }

    while(sc.hasNextLine()){
        s = new Scanner(sc.nextLine());
        while(s.hasNext()){

            String words = s.nextLine();
            if(!getTagValues(words).isEmpty() ){
                try {

                    question.add(getTagValues(words).toString());

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
      }
    }
       return question;
   }
```

And i don't know where i need to add code to get path and alse if i use .getAbsolutePath befor i got list like this 
[value from log],[Path] or worst [],[Path] because sometimes log haven't error so answer is empty.

Comment: Where in the code do you want to use the file ? The meaning is not very clear. Please edit and make the question clear.

Comment: Okay, sorry, but I have no idea what you're asking here.

Comment: format your code and question please

Comment: so... you have a list of files and want to get the file path of each one? Is that even close to what you are asking?

Comment: yes i need to get path to each one. 
Som Bhattacharyya i didn't ask for that i just want to know how i can get path value from List<File>

Comment: and you want to store that file path where?

Comment: I want store pathfile in question list if its possible.

Comment: you will need a Map or an Object that stores both the file and the path and put it in its own list (you can only put Files in your "listQuestion" list)

Comment: Great thank's i will try do something like you said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to determine the file path from File object, using Java 7 nio you can do that.

```
    file.getAbsolutePath() // where file is a reference to File object
```

Returns the absolute pathname string of this abstract pathname.

```
private static List<String> listQuestionE(Scanner sc, List<File> listQuestion){

       List<String> question = new ArrayList<String>();
       for(File input1 : listQuestion){
           try {
              String fPath = input1.getAbsolutePath(); 
              sc = new Scanner(input1);
              question.add(fPath);
           } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
       return question;
}
```

Comment: Your answer evaluate quickly :) I will try your solution and replay ASAP